# MudBlazor css and js fails to load when running as Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, .net-6.0, msix, mudblazor

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here, but I am unable to run a "Blazor Server" app with MudBlazor as a Windows Service (installed via MSIX), since loading the MudBlazor css and js fails with 404.

This is how to reproduce the problem I am facing:

Use the MudBlazor template to get started:

```
mkdir -p mud-test/MyApplication
dotnet new mudblazor --host server --name MyApplication -o mud-test/MyApplication
dotnet add mud-test/MyApplication/MyApplication.csproj package "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices"
dotnet new sln -n MyApp -o mud-test
dotnet sln mud-test/MyApp.sln add mud-test/MyApplication/MyApplication.csproj
```

Now open the solution file in VS2022. We need to make a few modifications to enable running in a Windows Service:

1. Open `Program.cs`
2. Replace the line `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` with:

   ```
   var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
   {
       Args = args,
       ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
   });

   builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
   ```

Add a new project of the type `Windows Application Packaging Project` called `Installer`. Just leave the platform versions at the default values. Then add a reference to the `MyApplication` project.
Open the `Package.appxmanifest` file in code view, and add this:

1. Add this namespace reference as an extra attribute on the Package element: `xmlns:desktop6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/6"`
2. Add this element under the `Application` element:

   ```
   <Extensions>
       <desktop6:Extension
           Category="windows.service"
           Executable="MyApplication\MyApplication.exe"
           EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
           <desktop6:Service
               Name="MyApplication"
               StartupType="auto"
               StartAccount="localService">
           </desktop6:Service>
       </desktop6:Extension>
   </Extensions>
   ```
3. Add this element under the `Capabilities` element: `<rescap:Capability Name="packagedServices"/>`

Once this is done, we are ready to build the installer:

1. Right-click the `Installer` project and select `Publish -> Create App Packages...`
2. Use the default distribution method of "Sideloading", but uncheck the `Enable automatic updates`
3. Create a new self-signed certificate, and trust it
4. Click `Create` on the `Select and configure packages` screen, to accept all the defaults

When the installer has been built, open a PowerShell window with administrator priviledges, and navigate to the output folder of the installer build. Then run the `Install.ps1` script to install the service.

Now, open a browser and navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` ... which should load the sample app, but giving 404 on both the `MudBlazor.min.css` and `Mudblazor.min.js` assets

Comment: Why change the `ContentRootPath` when app is running as windows service?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos This is needed on .net 6 as far as I can understand, and is what Microsoft says in their documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#app-configuration-1

Answer (score 2):

I temporarily worked around this by hosting the `MudBlazor.min.css` & `MudBlazor.min.js` files externally, and then loading them from there instead of from the `_content`.

This is by no means a good solution, so I am still eager to hear if anybody knows how to make it work properly